# First word from PascalCase as lowercase

Tags: groovy, pascalcasing

I have a string that contains text in PascalCase and I need to extract first word from it and convert it to lowercase:

```
assert firstWord('PmdExtension') == 'pmd'
assert firstWord('PMDExtension') == 'p'
assert firstWord('Pmd') == 'pmd'
assert firstWord('CodeQualityExtension') == 'code'

static String firstWord(String word) {
    return '???'
}
```

Let's focus only on valid PascalCase identifiers (without any other characters, numbers and always starting with capital letter).

What would be the simple and clean solution for my problem?

I've tried

```
word.split(/[A-Z]/).first().join(' ')
```

but it removes all uppercase letters, while I need to preserve them.

Comment: What have you tried? This looks like a "please write code for me" question (as opposed to "please help me with this problem").

Comment: @MichaelEaster I've edited the question and added info about what I tried

Comment: As you say, the split removes the uppercase, then just add it again since you still need to convert it

Answer (score 3):

```
assert firstWord('PmdExtension') == 'pmd'
assert firstWord('PMDExtension') == 'p'
assert firstWord('Pmd') == 'pmd'
assert firstWord('CodeQualityExtension') == 'code'
assert firstWord('') == ''
assert firstWord(null) == ''

static String firstWord(String word) {
    word ? word.split(/(?=\p{Lu})/)[0].toLowerCase() : ''

    // A verbose way would be as below (omitting the null check for brevity)
    // word[0].toLowerCase() + word[1..-1].takeWhile { Character.isLowerCase(it) }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
static String firstWord(String word) {
    return word[0].toLowerCase()+word.split(['A'..'Z'].join('|'))[1]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Groovy find operator (`=~`) seems to do the job nicely:

```
static String firstWord(String word) {
    word ? (word =~ /[A-Z][a-z]*/)[0].toLowerCase() : ''
}
```

Comment: If the person who downvoted me would care to express the reason here, I would be ever so grateful.

Answer (score 1):

The `inject` method can be used to accumulate characters until the second capital letter is encountered:

```
def firstWord(String word) {
    def numCapsObserved = 0
    def initVal = ""

    word.inject(initVal, { val, letter -> 
        def result = val
        if (letter ==~ /[A-Z]/) { numCapsObserved++ } 

        if (numCapsObserved < 2) {
            result += letter.toLowerCase() 
        }
        return result
    }) 
}

assert firstWord('PmdExtension') == 'pmd'
assert firstWord('PMDExtension') == 'p'
assert firstWord('Pmd') == 'pmd'
assert firstWord('CodeQualityExtension') == 'code'
```